# Plotting first few elements of array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two arrays that are each 56 elements in size. I want to create several different plots. The first plot would be the first 12 elements from each of the arrays.

```
x=np.arange(1,57,1)
y=np.arange(1,57,1)

plt.scatter(x[0,11], y[0,11], c='r')
```

this results in the error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How can I select only the specific elements from the array I want to plot?

Comment: I think you mean this : `x[0:11], y[0:11]` or either `x[:11],y[:11]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you should modify your array slice to:

```
plt.scatter(x[:12], y[:12], c='r')
```